# Move image behind the main content CSS

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I have a problem with some css in my website

```
this is the main CSS source :
/* html selectors ---- */

html, body {
    font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS';
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: white;
    direction: rtl;
    font-size: 10.3pt;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0;
}


h1 {
    font-size: 17pt;
    text-decoration: underline;
    top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 25px;
}

h2 {
    font-family: david;
    font-size: 11pt;
    color: #191970;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 16pt;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-top: -55px;
    font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS';
}



/*page -----------*/
#page {
    width: 900px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    direction: rtl;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    z-index: 5;
    background-image: url("images/bgimage.png");
}

#leftshadow {
    width: 100px;
    height: 900px;
    background-image: url("images/leftshadow.png");
    position: absolute;
    right: 840px;
    z-index: none;
    top: -25px;
}

#rightshadow {
    width: 100px;
    height: 900px;
    background-image: url("images/rightshadow.png");
    position: absolute;
    right: -45px;
    z-index: none;
    top: -25px;
}
```

My question is how can I move the image-shdow back, behind the main content?

I tried a lot with z-index but I couldn't find a solution, can you help me solve thos problem pleas?

Comment: Please post your problem in a fiddle. External site links are typically out of context and not useful to many other users.

Comment: Thanks, I will post it in Fiddle and edit as soon as I can

Comment: @Terry Here is a Fiddle, I can't insert the shadow's photos, it just didn't work... http://jsfiddle.net/AMk5f/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to use a `position` property in addition to the `z-index` property .. z-index will not work unless the element which has the `z-index` property applied to it is positioned using either:

`position: relative;`
`position: absolute;`
`position: fixed;`

Add one of those (relative preferably in your case) and it will work.

Comment: Thanks, but if I put it in position: relative, than the website's high is much more longet than I mean it will be

Comment: Add to the right shadow for example. with this code, I posted a fiddle in a comment, but I cun't insert the shadow image..): 
#rightshadow {
    width: 100px;
    height: 900px;
    background-image: url("images/rightshadow.png");
    position: relative;
    right: -1045px;
    z-index: none;
    top: -25px;
} 

I got this https://www.dropbox.com/s/505oor51i2cgf9t/%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9A%20%2835%29.png   (can you see the total height?)

Comment: Can you pleas help me with this ?

Comment: Thanks, so... what else can I do? I have to finish this today, and I really don't know how to silve this..

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reworking your DOM structure to accomodate for this case, something like this:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="page"></div>
  <div class="leftshadow shadow"></div>
  <div class="rightshadow shadow"></div>
</div>
```

check out this fiddle of the how the new structure might work - http://jsfiddle.net/wHgm8/

You could also, if you wanted a nice clean shadow around the page, use css3 box-shadow, example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ASc7J/ though support is for newer browsers.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your code:
**box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px grey;**
in above syntax, 5px is for left, 0px is for top and bottom and again 5px is for right. Play with the values untill you are comfortable. Also make sure you use hex values of color and is apt for a shadow.

Answer (score 0):

You need both a position command, and "none" is not a valid z-index value.  -1 works for me.

```
style="position:relative; z-index:-1;"
```